# How can I link background-image [vue cli]

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, webpack

when I'm trying to run this code below, I have a problem. It runs, but I can't see any images and it writes that url (unknown). How can I solve it. All images definately exists.

```html
<template>
  <div class="slider"></div>
</template>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("../assets/images/slides/2160/0.jpg");
}
</style>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Slider",
};
</script>
```

Thanks it works — [js vue.js]

```html
backgroundImage: `url(${require('../assets/images/slides/2160/0.jpg')})`
```

but what should I do if my path already use ${} for example

```html
"../assets/images/slides/${this.$assetsResolution}/${i}.jpg"
```

Answer (score 4):

try doing this:

```
<template>
  <div :style="bgImg"></div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        bgImg: {
          backgroundImage: `url(${require('../assets/images/0.jpg')})`
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but how can I use this method with this expression where ${} is already being used — "../assets/images/${this.$assetsResolution}/${i}.jpg"

Comment: does `url(${require('../assets/images/`${1}`.jpg')})` not work? images from the internet always works better.

Answer (score 1):

As Mentioned, use a field in data to get the image and link it to your dom.
The template:

```
  <div
class=" login d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
:style="{ background: ` center/cover url(${image})` }"
```

> 

the data object :

```
  data() {
return {
  image: require('@/path/to/picture/yourimagehere.jpeg'),
};
```

},

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to load it in `beforeMount` lifecycle hook

```
beforeMount(){
    const styles = {
      "background": url('../assets/images/0.jpg'),
      "background-size": "cover",
      "background-repeat": "no-repeat",
    };
    Object.assign(document.body.style, styles);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
 <div
        class=" search-box car-rims"
        :style="{
          backgroundImage: `linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.45), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45) ), url(
      ${require('@/assets/your-image.jpg')})`,
          backgroundSize: 'cover',
          backgroundRepeat: 'norepeat',
        }"
      >
        
      </div>
```